# Build - Maximum nonmagic Damage with Level 3 Character

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I am looking for a really hard damage dealing character for Level 3. Everything on [Pathfinder OGC](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) is allowed. Our world is a very very low magic world that means no magical characters. So open Classes are: Rogue, Monk, Ranger, Barbarian, Fighter, Gunslinger, Cavalier.

I have 5000 Gold to spend.

Really looking forward to see your suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean that all content and third party content is allowed or were you using that as a quick means to refer to the Paizo stuff rather than their site at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For damage/combat, with those stipulations, I would suggest one of the following three builds -

**Halfling Mounted Fury Barbarian 3**, taking the Bite power and later the Mounted Rager power as you get a better animal companion.  Ride a wardog to begin with, and carry a lance. Charging for double damage is generally the best way to do damage at low levels, and being on a Medium mount means you'll likely get to do it underground or in buildings or whatnot. Wield the lance in both hands for the 1.5x str to damage, spend your gear on str boosts and barding.  Your feats are Mounted Combat and Ride-by Attack, and then at 5th, you pick up Spirited Charge.  Cavalier's bonuses don't match up to what Barbarian can offer in terms of mounted combat.

*Note:* It's worth dipping Fighter at level 3 to pick up Spirited Charge earlier.  So Barb 2/Fighter 1.  Triple damage on a raging lance charge can end encounters at that level, and Ride-By Attack explicitly counts as a Charge, so you can theoretically circle-charge repeatedly.

**Thug Rogue 3**.  With the Enforcer feat and the that other one that makes you scarier, you can step up and beat someone to death while they cower in fear of you in a corner.  Eventually you want to pick up Shatter Defenses, so a Rogue 2/Fighter 2/Rogue X isn't out of the question.  This is the 'maximum damage' because with how 'batman' you are, you tend to last a long time and therefore deal the maximum damage.  You can build for Strength with this build, but I still tend to prefer Dex and using Agile gauntlets or something, as before you get your fear combo going you're still a squishy melee rogue.

*How do you damage them if they are running away?*  Corner them, then beat the heck through them.  Frightened means they try to run away, instead of taking other actions.  It doesn't mean you can't make them not succeed.  You can also invest in Combat Reflexes/Improved Trip line (see why Fighter dip is good) and knock their ass on the ground.  The great thing is that cornering, scaring, tripping people over, is it's all very Thug-like.  Themes are good.  The thing to keep in mind is, Intimidate checks add together rounds of Shaken-ness, so you can punch them multiple times to cause multiple intimidates to trigger the 4+ rounds = Frightened condition.  There's nothing wrong with pairing up with a Trip guy, or with a big barbarian who is going to leverage the rounds of time you are giving them to do a bunch of damage.

**Musketman Gunslinger 3**.  If you can control the tempo of a battle, the extreme ranges you can fire at as a rifleman, even with an arquebus rather than a bolt-action rifle, means you can quite easily kill foes without them even managing to make a spot check to see you.  Obviously, maxed hide, move silently, and spot are all valuable things for this character.

Comment: Wow! I really like the buid ideas. One question, how do you make damage on the Tug Rogues opponent? He flees so you would have to run after him?

Comment: @ruedi - Edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A nice build for massive amounts of damage would be an Invulnerable Rager(APG) with either Half-Elf or Human. If human, the bonus feat would be Exotic Weapon Proficiency: Tetsubo while a Half-Elf would take the alternate racial trait Ancestral Arms to take the same weapon.

If traits are available, then the trait Killer would be necessary as it adds damage on criticals.

Feats would be Power Attack(1st) and Extra Rage Power(Fiend Totem Lesser)
Rage Power would be Powerful Blow.

This build(with an STR of 20 base), while full rage/power attacking would be doing: 1d10+13 + 1d8+4
Maximum damage would be 35 without critical hits, or 122 with both attacks as confirmed criticals. This is without any magical involvement of any kind.

With a +1 weapon and a potion of enlarge person, the maximum damage(with crits) increases to 150 as maximum possible damage at 3rd level, at least as far as the core books and I can tell.